# Export objects in global and function environment to a cluster

Tags: r, parallel-foreach, doparallel

I am using foreach and doParallel on below sample code.

```
library(foreach)
  library(doParallel)
  clusters =  makeCluster(4)
  registerDoParallel(clusters)


  fun1 <- function(param1, param2, param3)
  {
     param4 = param1+param2
     param5 = param2+param3
     param6 = param3+param1
     print(ls(envir = environment()))
     print(ls(envir = .GlobalEnv))
     # clusterExport(cl = clusters, varlist = ls(), envir = environment())
     clusterExport(cl = clusters, varlist = ls(), envir = .GlobalEnv)
     mmm = foreach(i = 1:length(param1), .combine = rbind) %dopar% fun2(i, param4, param5, param6)
     print(mmm)
  }

  fun2 <- function(i, param4, param5, param6)
  {
  j = param4[i] * param5[i] * param6[i]
  }

  param1 = 1:10
  param2 = 2:11
  param3 = 3:12
  fun1(param1, param2, param3)
```

In clusterExport's  envir argument, when I use **envir = .GlobalEnv**, I get the error

`**"Error in get(name, envir = envir) : object 'param4' not found"**`.

And when I use **envir = environment()**, error is

`**"Error in fun2(i, param4, param5, param6) : 
  task 1 failed - "could not find function "fun2"""**`

My question is how can I export all objects in global as well as function environment to a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in a function, you don't need to export manually the objects you need. But you have to pass `fun2` to `fun1` if you want it to be accessed by the `foreach` in `fun1`.
So, just do:

```
fun1 <- function(param1, param2, param3, fun2)
{
  param4 = param1+param2
  param5 = param2+param3
  param6 = param3+param1
  mmm = foreach(i = 1:length(param1), .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
    fun2(i, param4, param5, param6)
  } 
  print(mmm)
}

fun1(param1, param2, param3, fun2)
```